# Change background of bottomnavigationtab

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I need to get such result as here

[image: my goal]

I tried do like this :

**my bottom_nav_menu_bg**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/home_btn_bg" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/gray_900"/>
</selector>
```

**My BottomNavView**

```
 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:itemBackground="@drawable/bottom_navigation_menu_bg"
            android:background="@color/gray_900"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/tab_color"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/tab_color"
            android:backgroundTint="@null"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            />
```

**my home_btn_bg for getting gradient color**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/black"
        android:endColor="@color/light_green_100"
        android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

but i got smth like that :

[image: my reality]

Comment: Looks like it is hard-coded with a fixed height, so this cannot be done with BottomNavigationView. https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/9a5192ae5e9689af5c4f43d8dd8084fec64894cb/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationMenuView.java#L116 You may have to use some other type of layout and manually map menu items to the views.

Comment: Thanks @Tenfour04 ! I just set height wrap content,

Comment: Yeah, you can do that. I just meant you can’t make them any taller.